# Android Room database throwing an error always

Tags: android, sqlite

Room is creating the db queries and I have checked the cursor-close() also
Any suggestion how to fix this one

```
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:300)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:138)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:219)
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:258)
```

Comment: Make smaller queries. Without a [mcve], it will be difficult to provide more specific advice.

Comment: From  your log shows it can't allocate  2048 kb buffer. I suggest you to use Paging Library It will handle it.